# Why is the variable empty inside an if block, but has a value outside of it?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, logic, conditional-statements

I found something I can't explain. `$post_id` is set to `9`, `$bookmarks` is an array with `[5] => true` in it. If I move `die($post_id)` outside this block and it **doesn't matter** if I put it **before or after**, `$post_id` will contain `9` but inside the block it has neither type nor value. How is it possible?

```
if ( !array_key_exists($post_id, $bookmarks) ) {
    $bookmarks[$post_id] = true;
    die($post_id);
}
```

UPD: I've edited the code, it now shouldn't confuse you.

Comment: what I don't understand is that you're checking if it's *not* in the array, yet wanting to return "true"; *why?*

Comment: I think you're looking for `array_key_exists`. `in_array` will look if the value is in the array, but it looks like you're using the post_id as the key and the value as a boolean.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner not quite, I check if it is not in array, then if it is not there I'm adding it to array. I mean it still contains 9 in it, why don't I get 9 then, just the blank screen?

Comment: anything from error reporting and what does a var_dump() reveal?

Comment: @jfadich yes, thanks, that's the function I actually needed, but still `$post_id` should give me `9`, isn't it? I mean that's the point of my question, I found a way to bypass the situation but I'm just so much curious.

Comment: That's not reproducible from this excerpt. Also shouldn't you be checking the array keys instead? (`in_array` only looks for values, and without strict matching: 9=TRUE, DUN DUN DUNNN)

Comment: Btw, tried [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) instead of [`die`](http://php.net/die)? Exit/die has two function signatures; only one of which behaves like an echo.

Comment: @mario yeah, still literally nothing, that's why I'm so curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`die()` is the same as `exit()` and [according to the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php), `exit()` has two distinct behaviors:

```
void exit ([ string $status ] )
void exit ( int $status )
```

It explains:

> If status is a string, this function prints the status just before
>   exiting.
>
> If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status
>   and not printed. Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254, the
>   exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The status 0
>   is used to terminate the program successfully.

So as `$post_id` is an integer, `die($post_id)` will actually print nothing and instead will just modify the exit code of the process.

You can make `die()` print a number by recasting it to string with:

```
die(strval($post_id));
```